# "Detached entity passed to persist" despite flush()

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a long running piece of JPA+Hibernate code that tries to insert a lot of records into the DB in a loop.

Over time (maybe because of the EntityManager cache buildup /  dirty checks), the rate of processing gets slower and slower. To resolve this, I decided to `em.flush()` and `em.detach(entity)` at the end of each iteration, because once an entity is persisted, I don't need its data for further processing (unfortunately I cannot use either `em.clear()` or batching, in order to reduce outside impact of my change).

Here is some rough draft of my code:

```
for (...) {
    ...some selects here...
    ...create new entity object...
    em.persist(entity);
    em.flush();
    em.detach(entity);
}
```

With this sequence, I get the "detached entity passed to persist" error for the entity detached in the previous iteration. **Why didn't the `flush()` before detach prevent the error?** Also, if I replace the `detach()` with `clear()`, everything works perfectly. **I was under the impression that `clear()` and `detach()` behave the same way?**

Even more oddly, I can reproduce the error within a *single iteration* with the following code. The "detached entity..." error is thrown from the *second* flush. **So does it mean that the first flush was a no-op?**

```
em.flush();
em.detach(entity);
em.flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

`flush()` synchronizes any change with the database, for instance if you modified an object and the call `flush()`, an update will be triggered. Note that you usually do not have to call it explicitely because the flush typically happens when the transaction is committed.

If you want to reduce the number of elements in the peristence context you need to call `clear()`. This will essentially reset the entity manager

Comment: Two things: If I don't flush, I can't remove the object from the persistence context (with either clear() or detach()), because I'll lose changes. The JPA docs say as much explicitly. And if I don't remove the object from persistence context, it builds up over time.
Second thing - why does clear work but not detach? Arent they both for removing entities from persistence context?

Comment: You might have multiple problems at the same time because you say it fails on the 1st iteration. The issue I see with calling detach() is that you are only detaching one entity but you might have loaded other objects in the EM. I think it would be clearer to have one transaction per loop iteration; that would remove flush() and detach() from the equation.