# Detached entity is unexpectedly being flushed causing error

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Working on an old project, using Spring 3.2.1, Spring Data JPA 1.3.0 with Hibernate 4.1.9 and hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:1.0.1.Final.

This is all happening inside a single transaction.

1. I retrieve an entity from my implementation of `CrudRepository` and use some of its data.
2. Then I detach that entity manually by using `entityManager.detach(entity);`.
3. In the following line I fetch another entity from another implementation of `CrudRepository`.
4. When fetching the entity in step 3, JPA auto flush is triggered. During the auto flush, an error occurs saying `detached entity passed to persist`.

I understand the meaning of the message, but I don't understand why it tries to persist the detached entity in the first place. My understanding was that the detach operation removes the element from the persistence context, so during auto flush of the persistence context, the detached entity shouldn't be flushed since it isn't a part of the persistence context anymore. But that's obviously not the case.

I found a question describing the exact same situation: ["Detached entity passed to persist" despite flush()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66006260/6814738), but it wasn't answered directly. The answer said to use `entityManager.clear()`, but that clears the whole persistence context which is not what I need. I need to detach just this one entity and keep the other entities managed.

The reason I need to detach this one entity is because of some concurrency problems and unwanted overwriting of the entity state in the database.

Comment: Persist is called on flush when any managed entity in the context references something that isn't managed and the relationship is marked with the cascade persist option. What are you doing with the detached entity, and what might have relationships to it? I'm not sure why detaching an entity will fix stale data overwrites - sounds like you've got a mismatched cyclic object graph, where something is referencing the detached entity (or another version of it)